# Does the level of my pickpocket skill determine how much gold I can steal?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

During the Dawnguard quests, the trainer and smith Gunmar have 56,000 gold.

My pickpocket level is average, but the displayed success rate is still at 0%. Does my pickpocket level determine how much gold I can steal?

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

> The maximum amount of gold pickpocketable on an awake target is 3,102 (1% chance on a 15 Pickpocket skill target). 1,500 of this comes from perks. The most you can steal with maximum chance (90%) of success is 2,212. Alchemy and Enchantments will increase the chances of a successful Pickpocket, but will not allow you to pickpocket more gold at small chances.

This indicates that the higher pickpocketing skill level, the more likely we have to steal that amount.

Since you said that you were at 
an average level, it would be near impossible for you to pickpocket such a large amount of gold, thus why it gave you a essentially 0 % chance. Keep in mind that even if you were at the max level, it would still be very hard for you to get such a large amount.

**[Source](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Pickpocket)**